# Problem reading webservice with jquery?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

What's my function's problem? I want to read the response from my webservice but I just receive an error.

The browser message is:

> undefined- status:error

when I press the button I just see the error function of my jQuery call but I don't know why. Please help me.

```
function SetupCompanyInfo(companyID) {
    //alert('aaa');
    companyID = '1';
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '../../../Services/CompanyServices.asmx/GetCompanyInfo',
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: OnSuccess,
        error: OnError
    });

}
function OnSuccess(data, status) {
    SetMainBody(data);
}
function OnError(request, status, error) {
    SetMainBody(error + '- ' + request + ' status:' + status);
}
```

My webservice:

```
using System;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Script.Services;


/// <summary>
/// Summary description for CompanyServices
/// </summary>
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[ScriptService]

//[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]

public class CompanyServices : System.Web.Services.WebService {

    [WebMethod]
    public string GetCompanyInfo()
    {
        string response = "aaa";
        Console.WriteLine("here"); 
        return response.ToString();
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public string GetCompanyInfo(string id)
    {
        string response = "aaa";
        Console.WriteLine("here2"+id);
        return response.ToString();
    }

}
```

My aspx file,part of head and my button code:

```
<script src="../../Scripts/InnerFunctions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="../../Scripts/TabMenu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="Scripts/InternalFunctions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <div dir="rtl" style="border: 1px solid #CCCCCC">
                   <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="../../generalImg/Icons/64X64/settings_Icon_64.gif" 
                       style="width: 27px; height: 26px" onclick="SetupCompanyInfo(1)" /></div>
```

Comment: Is the url you entered visible to the browser? If not then that could be the problem

Comment: I try my address with command prompt...
I was correct!

Comment: try to check if the ajax function was able to connect to websevice(asmx).  via "Fiddler2"  http://www.fiddler2.com/

Comment: The ajax url is unclear..   try write  full url  starting with "http://"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Cip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943964/why-i-cant-read-my-webservice-with-jquery/2945151#2945151) was on the right path - you need to make the response JSON, and then properly access the JSON on the client side. Your ASMX method should look like this:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat=ResponseFormat.Json)] // <--- To make it JSON
public string GetCompanyInfo(string id)     
{         
    Console.WriteLine("here2"+id);         
    return "aaa"; //never call "ToString()" on a string...
}
```

And your client side JS success function should access the data like this (you need to access the `d` property for JSON generated by ASP.Net):

```
function OnSuccess(data, status) { 
     SetMainBody(data.d);  //"d" is the js object representation of the return 
                           //value from the web method. In your case it's just
                           //a string, but it could be a more complex object 
                           //or an array
}
```

When you call the method via ajax, you should pass in the right arguments as well. Something like:

```
data: "{'id':'" + companyID + "'}",
```

Comment: Please help me, I am try to debug it, do I need to change the URL? I mean I dont need add my function name at the end of my URL?

Comment: @rima, the "http://www.hiradsign.com/Services/CompanyServices.asmx?op=GetCompanyInfo" URL looks correct. Your function does expect an argument, so your `data: "{}"` needs to be changed to something like `data: "{'id':'test'}" `.

Comment: So we need to add our function at the end of our URL,previous time I didnt use,let me test.. sorry I bother u tonite ;)

Comment: @jball I dont need add & ??? sorry It is my first time using Jquery,very bad experience

Comment: @rima, sorry, I pasted the wrong URL - your URL above is along the right lines `http://www.hiradsign.com/Services/CompanyServices.asmx/GetCompanyInfo`.

Comment: @rima, It's got a learning curve, but it'll be better once you get a handle on the basics :) You definitely do not need to pass any parameters in the query string (i.e. `?id=something&test=name` is not necessary).

Comment: @jball : still I have problem jball :(( check http://www.hiradsign.com/seller/sellermanager/

Comment: @jball: check http://www.hiradsign.com/seller/sellermanager/  I think it worked,but how I can see my text?

Comment: @rima Try changing your success function to `alert(data.d);` just to verify that you're getting the data you expect in the response. If so, then the problem lies in your `SetMainBody` function.

Comment: @rima Also, your `data` parameter still looks incorrect in the SetupCompanyInfo function in your InternalFunctions.js file and the wagme function is referencing a nonexistant error handler `err`.

Comment: @jball: THnak u sooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo muccccccccccccccccchhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh :*) HUG

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your webservice only responds with plain text, while the jQuery request expects JSON in return.

JSON is a format that lets you send different datatypes (strings, integers, arrays, etc.) in a coherent manner. Note 18 on [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#cite_note-17) shows you a typical JSON response for a person listing.

Your response should look something like:

```
{"companyName": "Foobar Inc."}
```

And, if I'm not mistaken, your onSuccess function should be something along the lines of:

```
function OnSuccess(data, status) {
SetMainBody(data.companyName);
}
```

Now I'm not entirely sure about the jQuery function, but your response is definitely not JSON! :-)

Comment: AFAIK, the default response type of web services is XML, though the rest of your answer is spot-on.

Comment: But his jQuery AJAX call is expecting JSON:
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType: "json",

Bah, cant figure out how to format this comment properly..

Comment: Cip would u tell me do I need customize my URL?Do I need put my webservice function at the end of my webservice?

Answer (score 0):

What Content-Type does your webservice respond with? It should be `application/json` for a JSON response.

Answer (score -2):

Like you use them your OnError and OnSucces are functions that need parameters. Maybe try something simpler like this first to get more feedback:

```
error: function(status, error) { alert(status + " - " + error); }
```